# Rails 3.2 precompilation fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm a newby in Rails, and I'm developing some app with 3.2.0. So, all is good, it works on my local environment, but when I try to push it to Heroku there are troubles with assets - my css files don't compile into one application.css file, therefore my final application.css is clean (you can see it by link [my app on Heroku](https://radiant-scrubland-4660.herokuapp.com/)). There are no problems on my local machine. I've found some answers in Google and people recommended do the following command:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I tried to do it and got the following output:

```
/Users/marya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby: No such file or directory -- ruby /Users/marya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/rake assets:precompile (LoadError)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/Users/marya/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/b...]
/Users/marya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:9:in `ruby_rake_task'
/Users/marya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:17:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'
/Users/marya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/marya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `eval'
/Users/marya/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I don't understand what it does mean, therefore I need your help. My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

If you need another project files, please, just tell me about it and Ill do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you're having some rvm and ruby issues, what happens when you type 'which rvm' and 'which ruby'?

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be an RVM quirk. I ran into this using rvm + ruby 2.0.0-p247 and this worked for me:

```
rvm ruby-2.0.0-p247@global do gem install executable-hooks
```